# Vim does not redraw appropriately in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, vim

I am using [vim](https://github.com/nguisiautien/configs/blob/master/vim_version) with [youcompleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugin in terminal in Ubuntu 18.04. Every time the plugin triggers a diagnostic error, the current window has not been redrawn thoroughly. As you can see here

[image]

the signcolumn and cursorcolumn are broken. This status will last about 2~3 seconds if I don't press keyboard to fire redraw event.

My [.vimrc](https://github.com/nguisiautien/configs/blob/master/vimrc) config file was copied from my Ubuntu16.04 system, and working perfectly there. I also have that config file tested in Debian9 system, and found nothing abnormal.

Could someone give me a clue on it? I would appreciate any help:)

Comment: I found a funny thing that if I start vim with command 'vim -V9myVim.log' which means that a log of debug level 9 would be created in the current directory everything would be working perfectly.

Comment: I guess it might be caused by the gtk library since nothing went wrong before the installation of vim-gtk (for clipboard-copy-paste supporting).

Comment: Use the steps in https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2004/205 to see if some other plugin is interfering. Was your 16.04 system using them same version of Vim as the Debian 9 one or the 18.04 one? Have you tried using a newer version (say, from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim)), or `vim-nox`?